# How to compute the gradient of the norm for linear least squares?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, least-squares

I am reading about Solution of the Linear Least Squares Problem. Given the function $$f(\theta) = \frac{1}{2} \lVert y - \Phi \theta \rVert _{2}^{2}$$ To find the minimizer we need to compute the gradient of f. The text says that $$\nabla f(\theta^{*}) = 0 \leftrightarrow \Phi^{T}\Phi\theta^{*} - \Phi^{T}y = 0$$

Can someone help me and explain how to compute the gradient of f? I don't understand why $$\nabla f(\theta^{*}) = \Phi^{T}\Phi\theta^{*} - \Phi^{T}y$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The squared magnitude of the vector $y-\Phi\theta$ is

$$\lVert y - \Phi \theta \rVert^2=(y-\Phi\theta)^T(y-\Phi\theta)=(y^T-\theta^T\Phi^T)(y-\Phi\theta)=y^Ty-y^T\Phi\theta-\theta^T\Phi^Ty+\theta^T\Phi^T\Phi\theta$$

But $y^T\Phi\theta$ is a scalar, so $y^T\Phi\theta=(y^T\Phi\theta)^T=\theta^T\Phi^Ty$. So the righthand side is

$$y^Ty-2\theta^T\Phi^Ty+\theta^T\Phi^T\Phi\theta$$

Differentiating with respect to $\theta$ now gives $-2\Phi^Ty+2\Phi^T\Phi\theta$, and scaling by $1/2$ gives the result.

Comment: Thank you! Why does differentiating $\theta^{T} \Phi^{T} \Phi \Theta$ give you $2\Phi^{T} \Phi$?

Comment: That's a typo; I left off the $\theta$ at the end. But think about it: $\theta^T\Phi^T\Phi\theta$ is 

$$\begin{pmatrix}\theta_1 & \cdots & \theta_n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}\theta_1+\cdots+a_{1n}\theta_n\\\vdots\\a_{n1}\theta_1+\cdots+a_{nn}\theta_n\end{pmatrix}$$ which is
$$\sum a_{ii}\theta_i^2+\sum_{i\neq j}2a_{ij}\theta_i\theta_j$$ where the $a_{ij}$ are the entries of (the symmetric matrix) $\Phi^T\Phi$. Differentiating with respect to $\theta_k$ gives $2a_{kk}\theta_k+\sum_{k\neq j} 2a_{kj}\theta_j$. But this is just the $k$-th component of $2\Phi^T\Phi\theta$.

Comment: Thank you for your help!